# Jquery Append working reverse

Tags: jquery

I ask jQuery to append "`</tr><tr>`" but it inserts "`<tr></tr>`". Why is this? I know I can make a table working with `display: table-cell` and `table-row`, but it has to done with table. Thanks in advance.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Andelhofs/3Lp7Lxqe/)

```js
var colors = ["#FAE7D0", "#FEB186", "#935D37", "#483728", "#C57C23"];
var index;
for (index = 0; index < colors.length; index++) {
  indexRemain = index % 4;
  if (indexRemain === 0) {
    $(".color").append('</tr><tr>');
  }
  $(".color").append('<td><div name="' + colors[index] + '" style="background-color:' + colors[index] + ';" class="color-box">&nbsp;</div></td>');
}
if (indexRemain > 0) {
  do {
    indexRemain--;
    $(".color").append('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
  } while (indexRemain > 0);
  if (indexRemain > 0) {
    $(".color").append('</tr>');
  }
}
```

```css
.color-box {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="color"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The issue is because you can only append entire elements at once. Your logic is almost as if you're trying to build a string, not DOM Elements. Can you give an example of the HTML you're trying to build, as it's not easy to see what you're trying to achieve from your code alone.

Comment: I try to make the 5 color in a New row. Samen if 9, 13, 17,  and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you can only append entire elements at once. Your current logic is almost as if you're trying to build a string, not create DOM Elements.

Assuming that you want to store 5 colours on a single row of the table, you can try this:

```
var colors = ["#FAE7D0", "#FEB186", "#935D37", "#483728", "#C57C23", "#C00", "#0C0", "#00C", "#CC0"],
    rowCount = 5,
    $row;

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0 || i % rowCount == 0)
        $row = $('<tr />').appendTo('table');

    $('<td><div style="background-color:' + colors[i] + ';" class="color-box"></div></td>').appendTo($row);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lp7Lxqe/1/)

Note that I removed the `name` attribute from the `div` as it was invalid.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.